# perl script to recursively list all filename in directory

Tags: perl, file, file-find

I have written following perl script but problem is its always going in else part and reporting not a file. I do have files in the directory which I am giving in input. What am I doing wrong here?

My requirement is to recursively visit every file in a directory, open it and read it in a string. But the first part of the logic is failing.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my (@dir) = @ARGV;
find(\&process_file,@dir);

sub process_file {
    #print $File::Find::name."\n";
    my $filename = $File::Find::name;
    if( -f $filename) {
        print " This is a file :$filename \n";
    } else {
        print " This is not file :$filename \n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This code seems to work perfectly fine for me (ActiveState Perl 5.10 on XP). How are you calling your script? What *exactly* do you mean by "But the first part of the logic is failing."?

Comment: Which platform are you using? Which perl version?

Comment: "My requirement is to recursively visit every file in a directory, open it and read it in a string. But the first part of the logic is failing." By First part of the logic I meant , visit every file in directory. File check  is failing for me.

Comment: @TopCoder: That's the version of `which`, you want just `perl --version` or `perl -V`, or perhaps `$(which perl) --version` or `$(which perl) -V` if `perl` is not in your `PATH`.

Comment: sorry , this is the correct version : perl, v5.8.8 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

Comment: Any idea what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: @TopCoder - "failing" doesn't mean anything. Please specify *technical* details of what you expect the script to do on a specific example and what it does differently.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`$File::Find::name` gives the path relative to original working directory.  However, [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find) keeps changing the current working directory unless you tell it otherwise.

Either use the `no_chdir` option, or use `-f $_` which contains just the file name portion. I recommend the former.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict; 
use warnings;
use File::Find;

find({ wanted => \&process_file, no_chdir => 1 }, @ARGV);

sub process_file {
    if (-f $_) {
        print "This is a file: $_\n";
    } else {
        print "This is not file: $_\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: My mistake! Deleted bogus comment and +1.